# PrimeNG how to use path for better performance

Tags: angular, primeng

While using PrimeNG with angular4, if we add the following path into component or any module, which one should be used for better performance

should I use

**1) Full path**

```
 import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/components/panel/panel';
```

**2) Short path**

```
import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

What exactly happens? if I add 1st one then only related files are only added? or if I used 2nd then will it add all files from primeNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1) Full path and specific path

Importing elements declared in panel.js (node_modules/primeng/components/panel/panel.js) in this path. Required files are limited to the one used by PanelModule.

#### 2) Short and general path

By importing from primeng/primeng (node_modules/primeng/primeng.js), it imports all required files declared in primeng.js. Basically all the js dependency for all primeng modules.

The 1st one will reduce the size of your app by loading only the needed module.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable Answer.